# Bucket contents slowly disappear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I dump a bucket with water or lava on the ground, or anywhere else, it slowly disappears when it hits the ground. It's impossible to use. This happened after I installed modloader and the Better Than Wolves modpack. Everything works great, except the bucket. I don't think its a glitch or a bug, but I haven't ruled it out. I have restarted the game and so on, but I still have same problem! Any of you who might know whats wrong, or are having the same problem?

Comment: What modpack can you give us a link ?

Answer (score 8):

This is a feature of the Better Than Wolves mod pack, not a bug. If you don't like [Hardcore Buckets](http://sargunster.com/btw/index.php?title=Hardcore_Bucket) you can turn it off in the config files.